# How to delete node with two child nodes in Skew Random Binary Access Tree?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, binary-tree

While trying to perform deletion in the Skew Binary Random Access list, I usually return null value in case of single leaf as follows:

```
deleteTree :: Int -> Int -> Tree a -> Tree a 
deleteTree _ _ (Leaf _) = Nil
```

but where I have to delete a node with two child nodes, what do I replace that deleted node with ? (As in case of BST we usually replace it with leftmost element of the right tree). What would be the case for Skew Random Binary Access Tree?

```
deleteTree :: Int -> Int -> Tree a -> Tree a 
deleteTree _ _ (Leaf _) = Nil 
deleteTree i w (Node t1 y t2)
    | i == 0   = (Node t1 value? t2)               
    | i <= s' =  Node (deleteTree (i-1) w' t1) y t2
    | otherwise = Node t1 y (deleteTree (i - w' - 1) x w' t2)
    where
        s' = s `div` 2
```

Comment: To delete such a node, you merge its two children.

Comment: I think it's going to be replaced with the next element at (i+1) index in the left tree in this case

Comment: It's important that it _isn't_ just that the value at that node replaced with one other element.  You have to _combine_ the two children with a skew merge.